# Can’t ssh to pi4 on 5G, can on 2.4G

Tags: networking, pi-4

I’m attempting to set up MainsailOS on a pi 4B 1GB. After installing the OS from raspberry pi imager, I have attempted to connect to both its local ip and raspberrypi.local, which has worked fine when the pi is connected to a 2.4G band of my network.

However, the router automatically assigns 5 or 2.4G channels and any time the pi is connected to a 5G channel it becomes undiscoverable on the network; I can’t connect via a browser, ssh, and it doesn’t appear on an ip scanner. On the pi, however, there appears to be an internet connection, since it can get files from online sources during updates (ie updating raspi-config). I have spectrum wifi with the stock router. Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Check your router doesn't block connections between 5GHz clients (WiFi client isolation).  That feature is falsely advertised as security - I can't see what security it gives if nobody can reach the printer.